# c++ ppl.h for parallel_for in linux

Tags: c++, linux, ppl, parallel.for

I made project in windows using c++ and now I am trying to build my project in linux(ubunt).
However, I couldn't find ppl.h in linux.
I used a lot of parallel_for in my project.

What is the replacement can I use?

Answer (score 1):

[Parallel Patterns Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Patterns_Library) is Windows only. It is not useful for portable application, it is considered that [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) is best alternative for PPL.
I.e. for the parallel for you can use following:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp parallel for
#endif // _OPENMP
for(std::size_t i=0; i < foo; i++) {
  bar[i] = (baz[i] * quux[i]);
}
```

To enable OpenMP add `-fopenmp` flag for G++.

PS.

- [Microsoft VC++
  OpenMP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/build/reference/openmp-enable-openmp-2-0-support?view=vs-2019)
- [Intel OpenMP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-adding-openmp-support-to-your-application)
- [Clang OpenMP](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/OpenMPSupport.html)